# How can I get rid of these mysterious grey boxes at the margins of a div element?

Tags: html, css

I am having a mysterious problem that did not exist yesterday (you know those?). For some reason, these grey boxes are appearing at the edges of an element that appears when a user hovers over its parent element. they appear to the right and bottom. Essentially, everything below the check and x images is a div with a class of `.bottom`. I have set to `50%` of parent height and `100%` of its width. These are react components, so it may be a tad hard to follow. The `EventDetail` component is nested in the `Event` component.

[image]

```css
.eventcontainer {
 padding: 5px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 20px auto;
}

.event {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 960px; 
  border-color:#496DD9;
  border-style: dotted; 
  font-size: 0.5em; 
  height: 300px; 
  position: relative; 
  -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease-out;  
}
.event:hover {
   height: 400px;
   -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease-in;    
}

.event:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in 200ms;  
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: scroll; 
  -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease-out;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%; 
  font-size: 13px; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```js
const EventDetail = (props) => {
  const options = {
    color: '#DE5745',
    trailWidth: 1,
    strokeWidth: 10,
  };
  const containerStyle = {
    width: '100px',
    height: '20px',
  };

  const showUpdate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.dispatch(renderUpdate(props.id));
  };


  return (
    <div className=" bottom  hidden" >
      <p>Attendance</p>
      <div className="progressbar">
        <Line progress={(props.attending / props.capacity)} containerStyle={containerStyle} initialAnimate options={options} containerClassName={'.progressbar'} />
        <span>{props.attending}</span><span>/</span><span> {props.capacity}</span>
      </div>
      {/* <div>{props.attendeeHelperFunction(props.attendeeList)}</div>*/}
      <p>Description:</p>
      {props.description === '___' ? <p>The owner did not provide a description. So mysterious</p> : <p>{props.description}</p>}
      {window.localStorage.getItem('userid') === props.owner_id ?
        <div>
          <Update
            event_title={props.title}
            event_description={props.description}
            event_capacity={props.capacity}
            event_id={props.event_id}
          />
        </div>
        : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const Event = (props) => {
  const attendHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.dispatch(attendEvent(props.id))
    .then(() => {
      props.dispatch(fetchEvents());
    });
  };

  const flakeHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.dispatch(flakeEvent(props.id))
    .then(() => {
      props.dispatch(fetchEvents());
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <div className="event">
      <section className="eventdescription">
        <p>{props.title}</p>
        <p>{props.date}</p>
        <p>Hosted by: {props.owner}</p>
        <p>{console.log('EVENT', renderEvents)}</p>
      </section>
      <section className="attend"><img onClick={attendHandler}className="eventgraphic" src={check} alt="" /></section>
      <section className="unattend"><img onClick={flakeHandler}className="eventgraphic" src={crossout} alt="" /></section>
      <EventDetail
        title={props.title}
        event_id={props.id}
        owner_id={props.owner_id}
        attending={props.attendees}
        capacity={props.capacity}
        description={props.description}
        attendeeList={props.attendeeList}
        attendeeHelperFunction={props.attendeeHelperFunction}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

They are scrollbars, duh! But if anyone ever stumbles onto this thread, here is a style generator for scroll bars https://mikethedj4.github.io/Webkit-Scrollbar-Generator/